# Difference between controller in struts-config.xml and filter/filter-mapping in web.xml?

Tags: struts

In struts project,before going to action class, we can restrict by using filter tag in web .xml and controller tag in `struts-config.xml`.

what is the difference between these two?, and which one is better, and why?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. The controller is the Struts 1 mechanism to determine what action gets called. What specifically are you talking about re: a filter?

Comment: Filters are like filtering something before we proceed and controller is deciding where to flow once our basic conditions are met. Simple english. In details look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/1666906/1844148
http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/what-is-a-filter-and-how-do-i-use-it.html

Answer (score 0):

May be you are new to Struts, and by the name `Controller`, you misunderstood that it controls the user access to the page, which is wrong. Controller in struts is used for action mappings, resource bundling and other things.